# Необработанное исключение в "0x76f215ee"

Tags: c++

При запуске получаю ошибку: "Необработанное исключение"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
struct ZNAK
{
    string surname;
    string  name;
    char  zodiak;
    int bday[3];
     ZNAK& operator+( ZNAK& op2)
    {   ZNAK temp;
    temp.surname = surname + op2.surname; 
        return  temp;
    }

};
template <typename T>
class TMen
{private:
protected:
    T *mas;
    int n;
public:
    TMen()
    {n=2;mas=new T[n];}
    TMen(int k)
    {n=k;mas=new T[n];}
    TMen(const TMen &Men)
    {
        if (this==&Men) return ;
        this->n=Men.n;
        mas=new T[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            mas[i]=Men.mas[i];
    }

    virtual ~TMen()
    { delete []mas; }
    virtual void input()=0;
    virtual void output()=0;
    virtual void output(string in)=0;
};
class people :public TMen<ZNAK>
{
public:
    people():TMen<ZNAK>(){;};
    people(int k):TMen<ZNAK>(k){;};
    people(const people &St):TMen<ZNAK>(St){;};
    virtual void input()
    {
        cout<<"Input info for "<<n <<" peoples"<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cout<<"Input surname: ";
            cin>>mas[i].surname;
            cout<<"Input name:  ";
            cin>>mas[i].name;
            cout<<"Input zodiak:  ";
            cin>>mas[i].zodiak;
            cout<<"Input day, month and year birthday:  ";
            cin>>mas[i].bday[0]>>mas[i].bday[1]>>mas[i].bday[2];

        }
        this->sort();
    };
    virtual void sort()
    {
        int mas_days[13]={0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334,365};
        ZNAK temp;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i;j<n;j++)
            {
                if((mas[i].bday[0]+mas_days[mas[i].bday[1]-1]+mas[i].bday[2]*365)>(mas[j].bday[0]+mas_days[mas[j].bday[1]-1]+mas[j].bday[2]*365))
                {
                    temp=mas[i];
                    mas[i]=mas[j];
                    mas[j]=temp;

                }
            }
        }
    }
    virtual void output()
    {
        cout << endl;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            cout<<mas[i].surname<<'\t'<<mas[i].name<<'\t'<<mas[i].zodiak<<'\t'<<mas[i].bday[0]<<'.'<<mas[i].bday[1]<<'.'<<mas[i].bday[2]<<'\n';
    };
    virtual void output(string in)
    {
        int k=0;
        string name, surname;
        if(in=="name")
        {
            cout << "Input name: ";
            cin >> name;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                if(name==mas[i].name)
                { 
                    cout<<mas[i].surname<<'\t'<<mas[i].name<<'\t'<<mas[i].zodiak<<'\t'<<mas[i].bday[0]<<'.'<<mas[i].bday[1]<<'.'<<mas[i].bday[2]<<'\n';
                    k=1;
                }
            if(k==0) cout << "No information on this name" << endl;
        }

        if(in=="surname")
        {
            cout << "Input surname: ";
            cin >> surname;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                if(surname==mas[i].surname)
                { 
                    cout<<mas[i].surname<<'\t'<<mas[i].name<<'\t'<<mas[i].zodiak<<'\t'<<mas[i].bday[0]<<'.'<<mas[i].bday[1]<<'.'<<mas[i].bday[2]<<'\n';
                    k=1;
                }
            if(k==0) cout << "No information on this surname" << endl;
        }
    };

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{  // ZNAK*ob1 = new ZNAK;
    //ZNAK*ob2 = new ZNAK;
    //ZNAK*ob3 = ob1 + ob2;
    ZNAK ob1;
    ob1.surname="Ivanov";
    ZNAK ob2;
    ob2.surname="Sidorov";
    ZNAK ob3 = ob1+ob2;
    cout<<ob3.surname<<endl;
    people st1(2);
    people *p;
    st1.input();
    people st2(st1);
    st2.output();
    st2.output("name");
    st2.output("surname");
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZNAK**&** operator+( ZNAK& op2)

**&** - не нужен, `operator+` должен возвращать новый объект, ссылку на существующий объект возвращает `+=` (потому именно рекомендуют использовать `+=`, т.к. это не порождает лишнюю копию).

Параметр ZNAK& op2 должен быть **const**, это может быть ссылка на временный объект